# Validate a specific element of an unvalidated XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, .net-6.0, xmldocument, xmlschema

I have legacy XML documents that contain nested (non-root) elements that I want to validate against an XML Schema. The schema itself **does not** describe the XML document as a whole, but only a particular nested element.

The XML document resembles a message received from a 3rd party system, has no `xmlns` attributes, and even no XML processing instruction. It's a legacy thing that I cannot influence. Example:

```
<XM>
    <MH> … nested header elements … </MH>
    <MD>
        <RECSET>
            … payload elements go here …
        </RECSET>
   </MD>
</XM>
```

My aim is to validate `/XM/MD/RECSET` against an XSD which defines the `RECSET` element and any payload elements nested within. I do not have schemas that would describe the outer elements, i.e. `XM`, `MH`, `MD`. I *could* modify all existing schemas and add dummy definitions, e.g. allowing for `xs:all`, but that is not preferred.

The validation is an optional step in a processing pipeline, and I want to avoid unnecessarily repeated XML parsing and other processing which adds execution time (throughput is important).

Another constraint is that I want to use `XmlDocument`, because down the processing pipeline I need an `XmlDocument` instance to perform deserialization into an object model using `XmlSerializer`. Again, this is an existing solution that I want to preserve.

My attempt is as follows:

```
// build an XmlDocument instance as the intermediate format of the message
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(msg.TransportMessage);

// obtain a pre-cached XmlSchemaSet instance matching the message represented by XmlDocument
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = … ;

// find the whole payload represented by the RECSET element
var nodeToValidate = xml.SelectSingleNode("/XM/MD/RECSET");

// attach schemas to the document and validate the payload node
xml.Schemas = xsd;
xml.Validate(ValidationCallback, nodeToValidate);
```

This results in an error:

> Schema information could not be found for the node passed into Validate. The node may be invalid in its current position. Navigate to the ancestor that has schema information, then call Validate again.

I've looked into the implementation of `XmlDocument` and the [`DocumentSchemaValidator` class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml/src/System/Xml/Dom/DocumentSchemaValidator.cs), which, in case of specific node validation, searches the DOM for schema information. Hence I tried attaching a reference to the correct schema to the node ad hoc:

```
XmlAttribute noNamespaceAttribute =  xml.CreateAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema-instance");
foreach (XmlSchemaElement x in schemaSet.GlobalElements.Values)
{
    if (x.Name == "RECSET")
    {
        noNamespaceAttribute.InnerText = x.SourceUri!;
        break;
    }
}
nodeToValidate.Attributes!.Append(noNamespaceAttribute);
```

However, that results in the very same error message.

A working way to achieve such validation is to take the `nodeToValidate.OuterXml` and parse it either using a validating `XmlReader` or a new `XmlDocument` instance. However, that leads to another overhead in terms of memory and CPU. I'd rather avoid this route.

Is there a way to tell the validation engine to validate a particular node against an explicitly specified schema?

Comment: Is the schema embedded in the XML file?  in some file on disk?  Available via the web?

Comment: According to the docs for [`XmlDocument.Validate(ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler, XmlNode nodeToValidate)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmldocument-validate(system-xml-schema-validationeventhandler-system-xml-xmlnode)): *The Validate method performs infoset augmentation. Specifically, after successful validation, schema defaults are applied, text values are converted to atomic values as necessary, and type information is associated with validated information items.* Do you need **infoset augmentation**?

Comment: If you don't need to do infoset augmentation and only need to validate, you can do so using an `XmlNodeReader` created from `nodeToValidate`, see my [mcve] here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zdi3Fu and fixed using `XmlNodeReader` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NFuK2t.  Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @dbc No, schemas are in external files. I'm building a `XmlSchemaSet` instance separately. The doc itself is 'plain XML'. The second dotnetfiddle seems like the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem** is that [`XmlDocument.Schemas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.schemas?view=net-6.0) is intended to represent the schema for the **entire document**:

> The schemas contained in an XmlSchemaSet object associated with an XmlDocument object are used for validation when the Validate method of an XmlDocument is executed.

In your case you have no schema for the entire document, so when you attempt to validate a particular node of the document by setting `XmlDocument.Schemas` to be the schema **for that child node**, validation fails, perhaps because the validation code is unable to navigate through the root document's schema (which doesn't exist) to find the specific child schema for the child element to be checked.

**Options for a workaround** depend on what you are trying to accomplish when you call `XmlDocument.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, XmlNode)`. As explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmldocument-validate(system-xml-schema-validationeventhandler-system-xml-xmlnode)), this method actually performs two distinct but related actions:

1. As expected, it *validates the XML data in the XmlNode object against the schemas contained in the Schemas property.*
2. It also performs ***infoset augmentation***:

   > The [Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-6.0) method performs infoset augmentation. Specifically, after successful validation, schema defaults are applied, text values are converted to atomic values as necessary, and type information is associated with validated information items. The result is a previously un-typed XML sub-tree in the [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-6.0) replaced with a typed sub-tree.

Action #1 seems clear, but what exactly is *infoset augmentation*?  This isn't clearly documented, but one effect is to populate the contents of [`XmlNode.SchemaInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.schemainfo?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmlnode-schemainfo).  For instance, using the XML and XSD from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp as an example, if I validate the root element against the XSD and check the contents of `DocumentElement.SchemaInfo` before and after as follows:

```
var nodeToValidate = xml.DocumentElement;

Console.WriteLine("DocumentElement.SchemaInfo before: {0}", new { nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.IsDefault,  nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.IsNil, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.MemberType, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaAttribute, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaElement, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaType, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.Validity });

// attach schemas to the document and validate the payload node
xml.Schemas = schemaSet;
xml.Validate(ValidationCallback, nodeToValidate);

Console.WriteLine("DocumentElement.SchemaInfo after:  {0}", new { nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.IsDefault,  nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.IsNil, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.MemberType, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaAttribute, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaElement, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.SchemaType, nodeToValidate?.SchemaInfo.Validity });
```

The result clearly shows that `DocumentElement.SchemaInfo` has been populated.

```
DocumentElement.SchemaInfo before: { IsDefault = False, IsNil = False, MemberType = , SchemaAttribute = , SchemaElement = , SchemaType = , Validity = NotKnown }
DocumentElement.SchemaInfo after:  { IsDefault = False, IsNil = False, MemberType = , SchemaAttribute = , SchemaElement = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement, SchemaType = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType, Validity = Valid }
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TO9Rhi).

Further, it seems that `XmlDocument.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, XmlNode)` may actually insert additional nodes into the document, see *[XmlDocument.NodeInserted triggered on XmlDocument.Validate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52697564/3744182)* for one such example.

But do you really need to modify your `XmlDocument` via infoset augmentation, or do you just need to perform a read-only validation?

**If you don't need infoset augmentation**, you may validate an `XmlNode` by constructing an [`XmlNodeReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodereader?view=net-6.0) from it and then using the reader for read-only validation.  First introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static void Validate(this XmlNode node, XmlReaderSettings settings)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
        using (var innerReader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(innerReader, settings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                ;
        }
    }

    public static void Validate(this XmlNode node, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaValidationFlags validationFlags, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= validationFlags;
        if (validationEventHandler != null)
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += validationEventHandler;
        settings.Schemas = schemaSet;
        node.Validate(settings);
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to do:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = ...

var nodeToValidate = xml.SelectSingleNode("/XM/MD/RECSET");

nodeToValidate.Validate(schemaSet, default, ValidationCallback);
```

Note that you never set `XmlDocument.Schemas` with this approach.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NFuK2t).

**If you do need infoset augmentation** you will need to rethink your approach, possibly by programmatically generating a plausible [`XmlSchema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema?view=net-6.0) for the `<XM><MD>...</MD></XM>` wrapper elements in runtime and adding it to `XmlDocument.Schemas` before validation.